# Error when building 64-bit Z3 on Windows

Tags: visual-studio, 64-bit, z3

I followed the instructions to build Z3 on a 64-bit Windows 8.1 system with Visual Studio Community 2015 by running

```
python scripts/mk_make.py -x
```

but when I run nmake, I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(8848): error C3861:
 '_InterlockedIncrement64': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(8879): error C3861:
 '_InterlockedDecrement64': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(8915): error C3861:
 '_InterlockedExchange64': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(8969): error C3861:
 '_InterlockedExchangeAdd64': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(8979): error C3861:
 '_InterlockedExchangeAdd64': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(9026): error C3861:
 '_InterlockedAnd64': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(9036): error C3861:
 '_InterlockedOr64': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(9046): error C3861:
 '_InterlockedXor64': identifier not found
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you're running on a "VS x64 Native Tools" console.

Comment: Thanks, that did take me quite further (compiled many units), but eventually I got a new error:

api\z3_replayer.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts w
ith target machine type 'x64'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
\VC\BIN\amd64\lib.EXE"' : return code '0x458'
Stop.

Comment: The module error means that some of the object files have been compiled for 32-bit while others are for 64-bit. Make sure you start with a fresh build directory and that you provide the -x option to mk_make.py

Comment: Yes, that seems to do it. Thanks!

Comment: for anyone wondering where that is, it's at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat at least for that version. It seems to add a few extra env vars and probably stuff to the path, but I didn't fully check