# Compile errors for Z3's JavaExample.java test of java bindings

Tags: java, z3

I am trying to use Z3's java binding, particularly trying to run the Java example `JavaExample.java` that's distributed in Z3's 4.4.2 version.

`JavaExample.java` was compiling fine when I was using the 4.4.2 com.microsoft.z3.jar file. However, it would not run because the default `libz3java.dll` was 32-bit and my environment is 64-bit. I tried building a 64-bit Z3 with the `-x` flag for its Makefile maker `scripts/mk_make.py` but that generated an error when I ran `nmake` (posted about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286374/error-when-building-64-bit-z3-on-windows)).

Anyway, I then downloaded the binary for Z3 4.3.2 version, which contained a 64-bit `libz3java.dll`. However, *now* `JavaExample.java` doesn't compile, generating a ton of errors, such as:

```
FiniteDomainNum cannot be resolved to a type    Z3Example.java  line 2222
```

for line

```
FiniteDomainNum s1 = (FiniteDomainNum)ctx.mkNumeral(1, s);
```

There are hundreds of such errors.

The jar file is properly included in the Eclipse project, just like the 4.4.2 was when `JavaExample.java` was compiling.

Any help on getting this going? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors are likely due to the fact that com.microsoft.z3.jar is missing or incomplete. You need to sort out the compilation issues described in the other post before the Java API will behave as it should.

Comment: Managed to compile a x64 version, now getting a new error. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288914/z3-java-binding-error-the-operating-system-cannot-run-1