# Error when running Z3 java binding

Tags: java, z3

I am running JavaExample.java provided with Z3 4.4.2 but I get the following output and then error:

```
Z3 Major Version: 4
Z3 Full Version: 4.3.2.0
SimpleExample
Opt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.microsoft.z3.Native.INTERNALmkOptimize(J)J
    at com.microsoft.z3.Native.INTERNALmkOptimize(Native Method)
    at com.microsoft.z3.Native.mkOptimize(Native.java:5208)
    at com.microsoft.z3.Optimize.<init>(Optimize.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.z3.Context.mkOptimize(Context.java:3043)
    at Z3Example.optimizeExample(Z3Example.java:2323)
    at Z3Example.main(Z3Example.java:2362)
```

To be fair, I am using the 64-bit `libz3java.dll` provided with 4.3.2, while using the *jar* file `com.microsoft.z3.jar` from version 4.4.2, because that was the only combination that I managed to get working ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286636/compile-errors-for-z3s-javaexample-java-test-of-java-bindings) details those problems). Could that be the version difference the reason for this error, or is there something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the version difference is responsible for this issue: 4.3.2 did not support optimization and thus doesn't come with mkOptimize. I'll take a look at the other issue separately.