# Z3 java binding error: "The operating system cannot run %1"

Tags: java, z3

When I run Z3's JavaExample.java to test the java bindings, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\git\z3\build\libz3java.dll: The operating system cannot run %1
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at com.microsoft.z3.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:14)
    at com.microsoft.z3.Global.ToggleWarningMessages(Global.java:86)
    at JavaExample.main(JavaExample.java:2347)
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: What flavour/version of java are you using? Note that a 64-bit Z3 dll can only be used by a 64-bit Java, but on many 64-bit systems a 32-bit Java is installed. That particular error message does not come from either Z3 or it's Java API, it comes from your Java installation and/or your operating system and most likely it means that either libz3.dll or libz3java.dll could not be loaded.

Comment: I'm running Java 1.8.0_65, 64-bit. To make sure I printed System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"), and did get 64. I compiled Z3 from scratch in a VS Native x64 prompt, with -x and --java options. Any other possibilities?

Comment: libz3.dll and libz3java.dll needs to be in the PATH on Windows, and possibly also in java.library.path. Since it seems to be attempting to "run" something when it should "load" a dll, there may be other factors involved (e.g., Eclipse?). Before going there, make sure everything works on the command line.

Comment: Bingo! It was the need to set the PATH. Thanks a lot! Might be a good idea to put this in the https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3 page and Leo's entry about java bindings, comments there show people were having trouble.

Comment: Leo's blog post is way out of date, that should be replaced really. As of yet I'm not sure about the PATH issue; it appears that some systems look for libz3java.dll in the same directory as it's parent libz3.dll and some systems don't. Another likely candidate is the default configuration of eclipse which might not be set up the same way as the command line.